# NextJs - Tailwind css class styles not applied on responsive screen

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am trying to add a custom class on a div that should applied only on "md" screen. Doesn't work -

`<div className="md:myclass"/>`

tailwind-config.ts

```
theme: {
    screens:{
      'sm': {
        'min' : '320px',
        'max' : '767px'
      },
      'md': {
        'min': '768px',
        'max': '1023px'
      },
      'lg': '1024px',
      'xl': '1280px',
      '2xl': '1536px'
    },
}
}
```

globals.css // imported in my layout

```
.myClass{
 background: yellow;
}
```

I was a bit skeptical so just to check if :md is working or not, I added **"md:hidden"** and it does hides it.

`<div className="md:hidden"/>`

also checked if the class is imported correctly or not I tried adding the class directly **without md:** and found it to be working

`<div className="myclass"/>`

Is there any other way to add my own class for responsive design or am I missing something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add your custom classes in one of the tailwind layers defined in globals.css file. you can read more about this in [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-with-your-own-classes)

```css
/* globals.css */

@layer components {
  .myclass {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```